# Where is closedness of the unit ball used in the proof of Banach-Alaoglu theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I am reading Lax's and similar proofs of Banach-Alaoglu theorem and I couldn't find in which step is the closedness of $\overline{B}_{X^*}(1)$ used in the proof. Every step seems to be but the conclusion is absurd. Where is the closedness used?

The complete proof, but written a bit differently by another author, is as follows:

[image]

Then since the subspaces topology of $B$ viewed as an imbedded subspace of $K$ coincides with its weak star topology, the proof is completed.

Comment: @GSofer Yes, of course compact spaces are closed if Hausdorff. But the thing is I couldn't find where closedness is used in the proof of it's compactness, and I want to know which step would fail if closedness is removed.

Comment: The $x^*$ you find toward the end of the proof satisfies $\|x^*\|\leqslant 1$. So that's where you need closedness of your domain.

Comment: @AlvinL Yes. I understand now. Thank you very much.